# Options to play video with menu on iPad / iOS

Tags: ios, video, dvd

I want to play a video with a language-menu on iPad, like DVD menus. I've read on a forum that DVD-menu's are not possible, but this was an old thread.

What are the options nowadays to play a Video with Custom Menu on iPad?

**EDIT:**

What I want to do exactly is let the viewer choose the language of the movie (subtitles).
This would be done by a DVD-like menu, with video in the background. This is important, because it's for presentations.

I learned that DivX supports menu's, so I'm trying thit at the moment, but the software to do this is pretty bad.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are looking for? You are correct that you cannot rip a DVD menu and have it be interactive on an iPad like it would be in a DVD player. However, there are certain iPad applications that allow for you to choose between languages and subtitles. If you can clarify exactly what you would like someone should be able to provide some guidance.

Comment: Does it have to a be a menu or would the out-of-the-box subtitle support in Videos be enough?

Comment: Yes, it has to be a custom menu. I'm trying out the DivX-menu's now, but I'm not sure if it will work on iPad DivX players. And the software to create this is al Windows-based..